# Node packages work locally but not when deployed to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I've implemented a very simple discord.js music bot which uses the node.js packages ytdl-core and opus-script. The bot is never able to join the voice channels and stream the music using the new packages implemented when deployed to Herkou, however the messages associated with each command such as the embeds still send.

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const streamOptions = { seek: 0, volume: 1}

const Discord = require('discord.js')
require('dotenv-flow').config()
const config = {
    token: process.env.TOKEN,
    owner: process.env.OWNER,
    prefix: process.env.PREFIX
}
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core')
const streamOptions = {
    seek: 0,
    volume: 1
}
const prefix = config.prefix
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('ready!')
    console.log(prefix)
    client.user.setActivity("foo", {
        type: "WATCHING"
    })
});

client.on("message", async message => {
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g)
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()
    if (message.author.bot) return
    if (message.content.indexOf(prefix) !== 0) return

    if (command === "play") {
        const link = args[0]
        if (message.channel.id === musicChannel) {
            if (message.member.voiceChannel) {
                if (!link) return message.reply("please enter a YouTube url to play!")
                if (!ytdl.validateURL(`${link}`)) return message.reply("pleae enter a valid YouTube url!")
                message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
                        console.log("Successfully connected.");
                        const stream = ytdl(`${link}`, {
                            filter: 'audioonly'
                        })
                        const dispatcher = connection.playStream(stream, streamOptions);
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        console.error(e);
                    })
                const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    .setTitle("__A New Youtube URL Is Playing:__")
                    .setThumbnail(client.user.avatarURL)
                    .addField("Current URL:", `${link}`)
                    .addField("Changed by:", `${message.member.user}`)
                    .setColor("#32a852")
                message.guild.channels.get(musicChannel).send(embed).catch(e => {
                    console.error(e);
                })
            } else {
                message.reply("you must be in a voice channel!")
            }
        } else {
            message.reply(`please use music commands in: <#${musicChannel.toString()}>`)
        }
    }

    if (command === "stop") {
        if (message.channel.id === musicChannel) {
            if (message.guild.voiceConnection) {
                message.guild.voiceConnection.disconnect()
                message.channel.send("successfully disconnected from voice channel!")

            } else {
                message.reply("There is currently no music playing!")
            }
        } else {
            message.reply(`please use music commands in: <#${musicChannel.toString()}>`)
        }

    }

}

});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Comment: Are you sure that Heroku has ffmpeg correctly installed? You may need to use a [build pack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest).

Answer (score 0):

Tried uploading it through github desktop? (no gitignore , upload it with the node-modules folder)